# Not able to multitask in Arduino

Tags: arduino, atmel

I've been trying to multi-task in Arduino but my code just prints the 'pHValue'. I'm not using delay() anywhere in the code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
void loop(void) {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  int pHValue = readPH();

  if (currentTime - prevTime > 50) {
    Serial.println(pHValue);
    prevTime = currentTime;
  }

  
  if(currentTime - prevTime > 100) {
    Serial.println("I got printed");
    prevTime = currentTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Juraj I increased the value of 1st if statement to 1000 and the second one to 500, not only the second if block gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two independent cycles you need two state variables

```
unsigned long prevVal; // Value printing cycle
unsigned long prevMsg; // Message printing cycle

void loop(void) {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  int pHValue = readPH();

  if (currentTime - prevVal > 50) {
    Serial.println(pHValue);
    prevVal = currentTime;
  }

  
  if(currentTime - prevMsg > 100) {
    Serial.println("I got printed");
    prevMsg = currentTime;
  }
}
```

If the cycles are not independent, (e.g. 100 is twice 50 ) you could do other tricks, but there's no reason or advantage here, I guess

Comment: prevTime is always max 50 away from currentTime, so the second *task* will never be triggered.